# Upgrade in CruiseControl .Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I have recently upgraded from CruiseControl .Net 1.4.3.x on our build machine to the latest version available from SourceForge which is 1.5.7256.1 and since then, the XML output (that is used by Cradiator and CCTray) contain lots more information than is required, as both output them straight to the screen.

For example, when code was broken, we used to have the name of the developer that broke the build displayed underneath, such as:

> My Random Project Name
>
> Breakers: JSmith, FBloggs

Now, we get:

> My Random Project Name
>
> NAntTask

I seem to recall that NAntTask is the name of the process in Task Manager.

I have checked for later versions of Cradiator but appear to already have the latest version, and am already using the CCTray that comes with CC.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer this from the point of view of the xml format and as a developer of Cradiator, which consumes the xml that CC.net outputs. 
(You mentioned Cradiator but didn't say whether it was having issues or if it was displaying incorrectly).

I won't be able to solve anything to do with the CC.net web front-end, however.

Basically, the xml format changed between 1.4.3 and 1.5, so it's likely that some component of what you're using, hasn't been updated.

CC.net 1.4.3 was the first version to include breakers in the xml.
CC.net 1.5.x changed the xml format.
An [example of the xml](https://github.com/PandaWood/Cradiator/blob/master/src/Cradiator/DummyProjectStatus.xml) is below.

This example includes the old & new format for demo purposes.

**Old** - > the breakers were in the 'CurrentMessage' attribute - as a raw string, which had to be parsed)

```
CurrentMessage="Breakers: bsimpson, jsmith"
```

**New** -> the breakers were in a new xml element tree 'messages/message' where the attributes defined info about that particular message eg

```
<messages>
  <message text="bobble, harry" kind="Breakers"/>
</messages>
```

Recent releases of Cradiator can read both these formats, so it should have no trouble.

If you can verify that your xml is the new format below (the xml is served at the url http://yourhost/ccnet/XmlStatusReport.aspx), then any issues may be old components (eg dlls?) not being able to read the new format.

The full example:

```
<Projects CCType="CCNet">
<Project name="Project 1" category="" 
         activity="Sleeping" 
         lastBuildStatus="Failure" 
         lastBuildLabel="1.4.1.3844" 
         lastBuildTime="2008-12-12T12:08:24.796875-06:00" nextBuildTime="2008-12-12T21:09:30.234375-06:00" 
         webUrl="http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/" 
         CurrentMessage="Breakers: bsimpson, jsmith" 

         BuildStage="">
         <messages>
            <message text="bobble, harry" kind="Breakers"/>
         </messages>
</Project>
</Projects>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the two pieces of information in my cctray notifications.

Did you keep your dashboard.config and ccservice.exe.config file from the previous version? That's where all these settings are defined (along with the xsl scripts to parse your logs) and you can keep them intact when upgrading from 1.4.3 to 1.5.7.